# Export from DataGridView to Excel & border around data

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

How could I create a border around exported data in Excel? I export the data like this:

```
For i = 0 To ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    For j = 1 To ds1.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j) = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create borders by setting xlWorksheet.Range.Borders.LineStyle equal to one of the Excel.XlLineStyle enums like this:

```
xlWorksheet.Range("A1:B2").Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

Borders.Linestyle will set the border for all sides of the cell by default. If you want to do only one side of the sell, you just add a borders enum argument to Borders like this:

```
xlWorksheet.Range("A1:B2").Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

Visual studio's intellisense will show you the different options for the xlBordersIndexes and XlLineStyles once you start typing

> EDIT: To highlight what you just exported, use the row and column count to define the range:

```
xlWorksheet.Range(xlWorksheet.Cells(1, 1), xlWorksheet.Cells(ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count, ds1.Tables(0).Columns.Count)).Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

Note that the code above is just an example for the first dataset you export, for the rest, you will have to modify the line slightly. The range start cell would have to be set to wherever you're beginning to export the second dataset to instead of just cell(r1,c1). And the end cell of the range would be cell([startrow + ds.rows.count],[startcol + ds.columns.count])...something like this:

```
Dim startrow As Integer = 50
Dim startcol As Integer = 1
xlWorksheet.Range(xlWorksheet.Cells(startrow, startcol), xlWorksheet.Cells(startrow + ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count, startcol + ds1.Tables(0).Columns.Count)).Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

Comment: thanks for response. I allready tried something like this, but you have to define range before that. That's why I intentionally showed my code for exporting from Datagridview - because I don't know the range of data, It depends on how many rows there are in Datasource ?

Comment: what are you trying to draw the border around, like around all of the data displayed? or column/row headers?

Comment: just around data being exported. I manage style for column headers separately. Thing is that I'm trying to do master-detail export, without exporting all tables data in same row.  In other words, my output is data from 3 queries which are exported one after other on same worksheet and I want to border around each to have a better look.

Comment: Oh, I get it now... Take a look at the edit and see if that helps. You just have to use two cells to indicate where the range should start and stop, and then set the border for that entire range. You can just use the dataset's row/column count for the first dataset export, but if you are adding more to the same worksheet, you will have to keep track of what cell you begin exporting the second/third set to and do a little math

Comment: thanks for this, It works. However I was hoping for something that might determine start row & column by itself, based on datagridview rows. Just because I do 3 different exports - 1st is not a problem, It's always just 2 rows (column headers and It's data), so I can fix that manually. But then I wish to do 2 more exports and those can vary a lot, in terms of number of rows. So far I've set those exports in same row (next to each other), but for better looks I was wondering If I could export them under each other. Have any ideas maybe ?

Comment: Well since you're exporting each dataset manually using indexes, you will know where the upper left corner of each export starts. If you'd like to export each of them vertically, you could dim an int variable (i.e. startingRowNum) before each export that holds the starting row number. Then, wherever you are referring to an excel row, add that variable to the row index. For the first set, that'd be 1. After each export, increment startingRowNum by the number of rows in the dataset you just exported, and repeat the process. Now rownum is 50 or whatever, so the next export will start 50 rows down

Comment: thanks for all your help. I'll try this too, I've actually found something simmilar and are allready testing It.